# Multiple placeholders for two Select2´s in same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, placeholder

It is possible to load "Select2" onto two selects with just one function.

**Jquery**

```
$('.selector1, .selector2').select2();
```

Now i´d like to add placeholders for thoose selects.
Somehow, i cannot do it in the HTML.

**Jquery**

```
$('.selector1, .selector2').select2({
  placeholder: 'selector1',
  placeholder: 'selector2'
);
```

How should the code look like?
Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/2475/),

You can use data attribute to get the required behavior, to get data attribute like `data-placeholder` you can use [.data()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/) as below

```
<select multiple class='selector1' id="e1" style="width:300px" data-placeholder="select a state">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
  <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
  <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>

<select multiple class='selector2' id="e2" style="width:300px" data-placeholder="select a city">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
  <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
  <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
  <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

Javascript :

```
$(".selector1, .selector2").each(function() {
  var placeholder = $(this).data('placeholder'); // this will get the placeholder from the control
  $(this).select2({
    placeholder: placeholder,
    allowClear: true
  });
});
```

Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data-placeholder` attribute and Select2 will automatically pick it up when you initialize it. This is because [Select2 supports data attributes](https://select2.github.io/options.html#data-attributes) for declaring configuration.

```js
$("select").select2();
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.1/js/select2.js"></script>

<select data-placeholder="First placeholder">
  <option></option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>

<select data-placeholder="Second placeholder">
  <option></option>
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="AK">Alaska</option>
  <option value="AZ">Arizona</option>
</select>
```